# User registration is not working in Rails 3 + Devise + ActiveAdmin installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

**I have installed the following gems:**
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
actionpack (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
activeadmin (0.3.4)
activemerchant (1.7.1)
activemodel (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
activerecord (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
activeresource (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
activesupport (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
addressable (2.2.6, 2.2.4)
ansi (1.4.1)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.1, 2.0.9)
aws-s3 (0.6.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
best_in_place (0.1.9)
braintree (2.9.1)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.21 ruby)
cancan (1.6.7)
capistrano (2.5.21)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
clearance (0.10.3.2)
cocaine (0.2.0)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
columnize (0.3.5, 0.3.2)
devise (1.5.1, 1.4.9)
diesel (0.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
exception_notification (2.4.0)
execjs (1.2.9)
factory_girl (2.0.4)
factory_girl_rails (1.1.0)
faraday (0.5.7)
fastercsv (1.5.4, 1.5.3)
formtastic (1.2.4)
friendly_id (4.0.0.beta14)
has_scope (0.5.1)
heroku (2.15.1, 2.14.0)
highline (1.6.1)
hike (1.2.1)
hominid (3.0.2)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
inherited_resources (1.2.2)
interactive_editor (0.0.6)
jquery-rails (1.0.19, 1.0.18, 0.2.7)
json (1.6.3, 1.6.1)
kaminari (0.12.4)
launchy (2.0.5)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.15)
meta_search (1.1.1)
mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)
multi_json (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
multipart-post (1.1.0)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
paperclip (2.4.5)
pg (0.11.0)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.1)
rack (1.3.5, 1.2.2)
rack-cache (1.1, 1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
railties (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.0.4)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.11)
RedCloth (4.2.7)
responders (0.6.4)
rest-client (1.6.7)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubyzip (0.9.5, 0.9.4)
sass (3.1.11, 3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.5, 3.1.4)
spoon (0.0.1)
sprockets (2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.5, 1.3.4)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
therubyracer (0.9.9)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9)
turn (0.8.3)
tzinfo (0.3.31, 0.3.26)
uglifier (1.1.0)
warden (1.1.0, 1.0.6)
xml-simple (1.0.12)
```

**This is my user module**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and     :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  def has_enough_credits?(value_in_credits) 
    self.credits >= value_in_credits
  end
  def add_outline(outline)
    if self.has_enough_credits?(outline.credits)
      user_download = Download.new
      user_download.user = self
      user_download.outline = outline
      user_download.save
    else
     return false 
    end   
  end
end
```

**Initializer de Active Admin**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

  config.site_title = "MyApp"

  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!

  config.current_user_method = :current_user

  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path

end
```

**Initializer de Devise**

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth. The first
# four configuration values can also be set straight in your models.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class with default     "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = "info@myapp.com"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments.
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, a valid remember token can be re-used between multiple browsers.
  config.remember_across_browsers = true

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  config.extend_remember_period = true

  # If true, uses the password salt as remember token. This should be turned
  # to false if you are not using database authenticatable.
  config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length. Default is 6..128.
  config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # an one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  config.unlock_in = 10.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 2.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper)
  config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

end
```

**Server Log when I submit the registration form:**

```
Started POST "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52 -0200
  Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"d0VNThc0pgYSYErb4mkP2AClbNNOYWb0qdD5H/IDgnk=", "user"=>{"email"=>"matismasters@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Completed   in 8ms


Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52 -0200
  Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /home/matis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-    0.3.4/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within     layouts/active_admin_logged_out (7.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 28.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52 -0200
Served asset /active_admin.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/vendor.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52     -0200
Served asset /active_admin/vendor.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/base.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52 -    0200
Served asset /active_admin/base.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52 -0200
Served asset /active_admin.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-nipple.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-12 11:25:52 -0200
```

Served asset /active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-nipple.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

**config/routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  match "index" => "site#index"
  match "search" => "site#search"
  root :to => 'site#index'
end
```

**Other details:**
The layout doesn't seems to be showing ok in the sign up page, but the form is rendered correctly, using the right method and the right url, checked in the routes with rake routes, everything seems to be fine. The result of submitting the form is that it takes me to the login page without doing anything, not creating the user, or showing any message.

Anyone has any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the logout functionality.  Needed to make sure I included jquery and jquery ujs on the pages where I had a logout button.  I guess you could configure logout in devise via :get, but I found the best solution was to make sure my scripts were loaded the way they were supposed to be.  Firebug tipped me off.